# Errors in PostgreSQL log

Tags: postgresql

We are getting this kind of error in replica's log after the
master cluster was down due to no space left issue.
More details:

```
LOG:  incomplete startup packet
LOG:  invalid contrecord length 4975 at 9412/F4FFE910
```

It it something critical?
Help will be deeply appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be hitting a recently discovered bug that was fixed with [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=ff9f111bce24fd9bbca7a20315586de877d74923).

Wait for the next minor release. For now, you will have to rebuild the standby.